# Indirect parameterized instantiation using Autofac

Tags: autofac

I'm getting a `DependencyResolutionException` trying to use Autofac's [parameterized instantiation](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/resolve/relationships.html#parameterized-instantiation-func-x-y-b) to resolve an *indirect* dependency.

Suppose I have the following classes:

```
public interface IMuffin {}

public class Muffin : IMuffin
{
    public Muffin(IButter butter) {}
}

public interface IButter {}

public class Butter : IButter
{
    public Butter(IKnife knife) {}
}

public interface IKnife {}
```

Now suppose I want an `IMuffin` but I want to supply the `IKnife` dependency as a parameter, like this:

```
public class Breakfast
{
    public Breakfast(Func<IKnife, IMuffin> muffinFactory)
    {
        var muffin = muffinFactory(new Knife());
    }

    private class Knife : IKnife {}
}
```

The problem is, I get an exception on `muffinFactory(new Knife())` complaining that the factory can't resolve the `IKnife` dependency of the `Butter` constructor using the available parameters and services. This makes no sense since I provided an instance of `IKnife` as a parameter to the factory.

This seems like it should work. What am I missing?

Comment: This is [an FAQ addressed in the documentation](http://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq/injecting-global-parameters.html).

Comment: Okay, I can see where they're coming from, but using parameterized instantiation for even _direct_ dependencies involves some "knowledge". And it only takes one little refactoring to turn a direct dependency into an indirect one. This is actually what happened in my case. Using the example above, suppose `Muffin` originally depended on `IKnife` directly, so parameterized instantiation by `Breakfast` would work. When `Butter` was factored out, `IKnife` became an indirect dependency, which broke `Breakfast`. `IMuffin` consumers should not be affected by such a change.

Answer (score 0):

The factory in your example is a factory for `IMuffin` and the your `IKnife` parameters is passed as [typed parameter](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/resolve/relationships.html#parameterized-instantiation-func-x-y-b). However, your `Muffin` class does not need an `IKnife` instance. It requires an `IButter` instance.

The `IKnife` instance is required by the `Butter` class. But the parameter you passed to the factory can only be used to create a `Muffin` instance and it is not used to resolve a dependency of `Muffin`. The correct type of your `muffinFactory` would be `Func<IButter, IMuffin>`.

To make your example work you need two factories:

```
public class Breakfast
{
   public Breakfast(Func<IKnife, IButter> butterFactory, Func<IButter, IMuffin> muffinFactory)
   {
      var butter = butterFactory(new Knife());
      var muffin = muffinFactory(butter);
   }

   private class Knife : IKnife { }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I tried that approach after posting. Since Autofac can walk a dependency tree, though, it seems like it should be able to carry along the parameters you specify to resolve any dependencies along the way, not just top-level ones. Disappointed that I have to hand-hold it to get the `IKnife` to be available at the second level.

Comment: It _very intentionally does not_ take parameters from the top level and pass them to every resolution down the entire stack. [See the FAQ.](http://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq/injecting-global-parameters.html)

Comment: @TravisIllig, thanks for the link -- that helps! Please see my response to you comment on the original question, though.

Comment: Saw the response, doesn't change the fact that it's a design challenge and passing things all the way down the resolution stack doesn't make sense. I believe that's pretty standard across IoC containers and the pattern in general - you shouldn't know the whole resolution chain.

Comment: I'm not saying it's great design to know _all_ dependencies in the _whole_ resolution chain. But Autofac clearly supports knowing about _selected_ first-level dependencies (hence parameterized instantiation), and also supports a convenient refactoring technique that results in first-level dependencies becoming second-level dependencies (Extras.AggregateService), so it seems a little strong to suggest that some great design flaw was introduced by using those two features together.